# how can a Jira workflow validator read the status of bitbucket pull request?

Tags: bitbucket, jira

I am trying to create a workflow validator that checks if there's an (open) pull request in the issue. The JQL for listing such issues is easy:
issue.property[development].prs = 1

But if I try in the Simple Scripted Validator

```
issue.property['Development'].prs == 1
```

I get the error that there's no property for the class com.atlassian.jira.issue.Issue

We're using Jira 7.x, and are testing the latest BitBucket version  for managing branches. Crunched the APIs, but to no avail: I can't get past reading the prs (Pull Request Status).
Note that Development or prs are no custom fields in Jira, but fields on the right side of the screen, coming from the integration with BitBucket.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it doesn't work because you spelled 'Development' with capital D. When I do this, I get zero results (but not the error that you mention about the property not being there).